# Postgresql near real-time

Tags: postgresql, database-design, trigger, postgresql-performance, functions

Before asking the question I will update you on the situation I face.

I have physical tables in postgresql that are continuously updated by various external flows (.NET, Java, etc...), at the moment there are some ETL functions written in plpqsql, scheduled every morning at 6:00, which have the purpose to take all the data from these source tables and bring them into final tables, which are consulted by other applications. ETL functions transform/relate data to each other. Here is an example of a query that is executed by one of the many ETL functions, this function uses this query to read from various Input tables to write to a single lookup table:

```
SELECT dw.unique_key,
    dw.id3_cod_compagnia AS compagnia,
    dw.id3_numero_polizza AS numpolizza,
        CASE
            WHEN dw.id3_cod_compagnia = '02'::text AND dw.lf_cod_age_gest = '0513'::text THEN (('0513'::text || dw.id3_numero_polizza)::character varying)::text
            ELSE dw.proposta
        END AS numproposta,
    dw.categoria,
    preferred.stato_polizza(dw.stato_polizza::character varying, dw.causale::character varying, dw.poli_cou_data_sosp IS NOT NULL AND dw.poli_cou_data_sosp > '0001-01-01'::date) AS stato_polizza,
    dw.stato_polizza AS stato_life,
    dw.causale AS causale_life,
    preferred.stato_descrizione(dw.stato_polizza::character varying, dw.causale::character varying, dw.poli_cou_data_sosp IS NOT NULL AND dw.poli_cou_data_sosp > '0001-01-01'::date) AS desc_stato,
    preferred.tipologia(tb10.prodotto_unit_linked::character varying, tb10.gest_separata::character varying, ca.gestione_separata) AS tipo_polizza,
    dw.durata_anni AS durata_polizza,
    preferred.durata_pagpre(dw.lf_dur_anni_pr_lim::numeric, dw.durata_anni::numeric, dw.dur_anni_pag_pre::numeric) AS durata_pagpre,
    dw.fk_cod_tariffa AS tariffa,
    btrim(tb10.descr_estesa::text) AS desc_tariffa,
    dw.cod_anagr_contr_ass AS ndg_contraente,
    dw.fraz_premio AS tipo_rateazione,
        CASE
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 0 THEN 'PR. UNICO'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 1 THEN 'ANNUALE'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 2 THEN 'SEMESTRALE'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 3 THEN 'QUADRIMES.'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 4 THEN 'TRIMESTR.'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 6 THEN 'BIMESTR.'::text
            WHEN dw.fraz_premio = 12 THEN 'MENSILE'::text
            ELSE NULL::text
        END AS desc_tipo_rateazione,
    dw.lf_cod_age_gest AS cod_agenzia,
    ( SELECT nodo.cragionesociale
           FROM life_public.intermediari nodo
          WHERE nodo.ckeyesterna::text = (((('9'::text || dw.id3_cod_compagnia) || '|'::text) || dw.lf_cod_age_gest) || '0'::text)) AS desc_agenzia,
    dw.filiale,
    dw.promotore,
    'now'::text::date AS data_estrazione,
        CASE
            WHEN dw.imp_prestazione IS NULL OR dw.imp_prestazione <= 0::numeric THEN NULL::date
            WHEN ( SELECT isramo1.isramo1
               FROM preferred.isramo1(ca.cod_universo, dw.fk_cod_tariffa::character varying) isramo1(isramo1)) THEN dw.data_ult_rivalut
            WHEN 'TRAD'::text = preferred.tipologia('S'::character varying, tb10.gest_separata::character varying, ca.gestione_separata)::text THEN dw.data_ult_rivalut
            ELSE ( SELECT rt.data_riscatto
               FROM life_landing.riscatto_totale rt
              WHERE dw.id3_numero_polizza::numeric = rt.polizza AND dw.id3_cod_compagnia::numeric = rt.compagnia AND dw.categoria::numeric = rt.categoria AND rt.riscatto_lordo > 0::numeric AND (rt.data_riscatto IS NULL OR rt.data_riscatto = (( SELECT max(rt1.data_riscatto) AS max
                       FROM life_landing.riscatto_totale rt1
                      WHERE rt1.polizza = rt.polizza AND rt1.categoria = rt.categoria AND rt1.compagnia = rt.compagnia AND rt1.riscatto_lordo > 0::numeric))))
        END AS data_riscatto,
    dw.data_eff_stato_pol AS data_decorrenza,
        CASE
            WHEN ( SELECT isramo1.isramo1
               FROM preferred.isramo1(ca.cod_universo, dw.fk_cod_tariffa::character varying) isramo1(isramo1)) THEN
            CASE
                WHEN dw.data_quiet_inc_1 IS NOT NULL AND dw.data_quiet_inc_1 > '0001-01-01'::date THEN dw.data_quiet_inc_1
                ELSE dw.data_quiet_inc_2
            END
            ELSE
            CASE
                WHEN dw.data_scadenza = '0001-01-01'::date THEN NULL::date
                ELSE dw.data_scadenza
            END
        END AS data_scadenza,
        CASE
            WHEN ( SELECT isramo1.isramo1
               FROM preferred.isramo1(ca.cod_universo, dw.fk_cod_tariffa::character varying) isramo1(isramo1)) THEN
            CASE
                WHEN dw.imp_prestazione IS NULL OR dw.imp_prestazione <= 0::numeric THEN 0::numeric
                ELSE dw.imp_prestazione
            END
            WHEN 'TRAD'::text = preferred.tipologia('S'::character varying, tb10.gest_separata::character varying, ca.gestione_separata)::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN dw.imp_prestazione IS NULL OR dw.imp_prestazione <= 0::numeric THEN 0::numeric
                ELSE dw.imp_prestazione
            END
            ELSE ( SELECT rt.riscatto_lordo
               FROM life_landing.riscatto_totale rt
              WHERE dw.id3_numero_polizza::numeric = rt.polizza AND dw.id3_cod_compagnia::numeric = rt.compagnia AND dw.categoria::numeric = rt.categoria AND rt.riscatto_lordo > 0::numeric AND (rt.data_riscatto IS NULL OR rt.data_riscatto = (( SELECT max(riscatto_totale.data_riscatto) AS max
                       FROM life_landing.riscatto_totale
                      WHERE riscatto_totale.polizza = rt.polizza AND riscatto_totale.categoria = rt.categoria AND riscatto_totale.compagnia = rt.compagnia AND riscatto_totale.riscatto_lordo > 0::numeric))))
        END AS valore_riscatto,
    ca.cod_universo,
    tb10.gest_separata,
    dw.conclusa,
    dw.id_codice_polizza,
    COALESCE(ca.gestione_separata, true) AS config_gest_separata,
    dw.tot_premi_pagati,
    dw.data_qta_storno,
    dw.lf_imp_prest_iniz,
    dw.unit_linked,
    dw.cou_blocco_cedola,
    dw.decumulo,
    dw.dt_revoca_decumulo AS data_revoca_decumulo,
    dw.dt_adesione_decumulo AS data_adesione_decumulo,
    dw.dc_misura_ammessa,
    dw.dc_frequenza_ammessa,
    tb10.emissione_cedole,
    dw.lf_pol_adeg
   FROM life_staging.stg_polizze dw
     JOIN life_landing.stato_titolo_life stl ON dw.stato_polizza = stl.stato::text AND dw.causale = stl.causale::text
     JOIN life_landing.wba_tb10 tb10 ON tb10.compagnia = dw.id3_cod_compagnia::numeric AND tb10.tariffa::text = dw.fk_cod_tariffa
     LEFT JOIN preferred.config_compagnie_agenzie ca ON ca.compagnia::numeric = dw.id3_cod_compagnia::numeric AND ca.cod_agenzia::text = dw.lf_cod_age_gest
  WHERE (dw.id3_cod_compagnia = ANY (ARRAY['02'::text, '11'::text, '28'::text])) AND dw.id3_indiv_coll = '1'::text AND dw.id3_tipo_prop_pol = 'P'::text AND ((dw.lf_pol_adeg = ANY (ARRAY[''::text, ' '::text, 'P'::text])) OR dw.id3_cod_compagnia = '25'::text AND (dw.fk_cod_tariffa = ANY (ARRAY['11S4'::text, '11S3'::text, '11AS'::text, '31UA'::text, '31UN'::text]))) AND (dw.stato_polizza = ANY (ARRAY['1'::text, '3'::text, '5'::text]))
```

The aim of my project is to make this ETL process near real-time, so you no longer have to wait until the next day to have the data updated, but have the data updated immediately. Some of my colleagues have recommended using triggers for each single source table and then unpacking the query and trying to get the same result, but with complex queries (like this one) the trigger becomes expensive to maintain. My question is: is there some kind of table/view/materialized view that allows me to have this real-time?

I am open to any kind of solution you have.

Thank you so much guys.

Comment: No, and you shouldn't try this. People keep dreaming about real-time data warehouses, but it is a contradiction in trems.

Comment: So what should I do? The customer no longer wants to wait a day for updated data.

Comment: Well, they have to wait. Tell them that's how data warehouses work. You could run the ETL process more often, but that means that they cannot query the data warehouse at those times.

Comment: Have you tried just querying the original data instead of the warehouse?  Basically turn the select (which I assume is the basis of some hand-rolled materialized view) into a view.  Of course you will likely need to add new indexes to support efficient querying, but that is a concrete thing, you would need to see the queries to know what might work.

Answer (score 0):

> So what should I do? The customer no longer wants to wait a day for updated data.

While Laurenz is right that the term "*real-time data warehouse*" is a bit of an oxymoron, I disagree that the answer to the problem is "*they have to wait*".

The first thing you should do is analyze how long the process currently takes. Then discuss with the customer what's the furthest from real-time that would be acceptable?...half a day?...every few hours?...every hour?...every 15 minutes?...every minute? This is a business problem that needs addressing first, as there's likely an acceptable middle ground that then drives your implementation decision.

If you ran the current process more frequently, you can utilize features of the database that would allow concurrent access to the data warehouse while the new data is being loaded. I'm not as familiar with PostgreSQL to make specific suggestions other than looking into alternative transaction isolation levels. In some database systems, like Microsoft SQL Server, there are isolation levels that essentially keep the previous version of the data available as it's concurrently being modified, so that readers of the data aren't locked and safely have access to the previous values, while writers concurrently update that data. I would imagine PostgreSQL has similar offerings. There may be other features that can be used as solutions too.

If you want something that's closer to real-time than every X minutes, then your colleagues suggestion of using triggers are likely your best bet. You can refactor the common ETL code into a single place (likely something programmatic like a procedure or function) that the triggers call, to minimize the technical debt. This way the core ETL code lives in one place.

Comment: 1. The query I attached is one of the most complex of the various ETL functions, it takes about 30 minutes, launching this refresh every time would use too many resources.

2. The option of converting the Query into many small triggers is not the easiest way, in the long run the triggers will reach too high a complexity for maintenance.

Comment: @LuisDiMatteo 1. Long running queries does not necessarily mean resource intensive. You have to analyze the query plan & server to determine if that's so. As I mentioned, if the customer is ok with data being as fresh as every hour or more, than you can schedule this more frequently. 2. I didn't say to convert this query into triggers. I said to call it from the triggers by centralizing it into a single place. 3. This query doesn't look unmanageably complex either & probably has some fundamental problems that can be tuned if it's taking that long. It may be possible to run it in under 1 minute